# Build queuing in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a couple of jobs that have to be built in a specific order.

Job A triggers Job B that triggers Job C.

Job D must not start before A-B-C has run it course. However this job (D) is in it's turn triggered by a repository change. As D has run successfully it will trigger A

Any way to block D until A-B and C has run?

/J

Comment: "Job D must not start before A-B-C" and "As D has run successfully it will trigger A". So is the order they should run A, B, C, D, A?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the "Throttle Concurrent Build" plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin

Comment: This will work only if D is officially 'running' while A-B-C do their jobs. I.e. D must trigger A as a build step but not as a post-build-action.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, you can make one category containing A-B-C-D and allow only one job to be run.